# How to calculate fine using datediff function in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures, datediff

```
  create function fine1(date1 date,date2 date) returns int
-> begin
-> declare fine int;
-> if datediff(date1,date2)>10 then
-> set fine=(datediff-10)*5;
-> return fine;
-> end;
-> //
```

I wrote this code but it's giving me an error.

Comment: what error, could you post error also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to be missing **[`END IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)**

```
  create function fine1(date1 date,date2 date) returns int
-> begin
-> declare fine int;
-> if datediff(date1,date2)>10 then
-> set fine=(datediff(date1,date2)-10)*5; <-- was not correct.
-> end if;  <-- was missing
-> return fine;
-> end;
```

Also, it seems like you are using `datediff` function for calculation where you have missed to pass parameters.

```
set fine=(datediff-10)*5;
```

should be

```
set fine=(datediff(date1,date2)-10)*5;
```